# What sort of algorithm does Dribbble use for their popular shots page?

Tags: interaction-design, social-interfaces

[image]
Does anyone have any insight as to the algorithm that Dribbble.com uses on their popular shots page?

Answer (score 2):

Even without knowing the exact algorithm, you can probably observe a few factors that come into the equation:

- **Views**: one way of defining popularity is the number of views that the shot has received, but because a person can look at a picture without necessarily liking it (and high views doesn't necessarily mean the work is of higher quality), it is only an indicator
- **Hearts**: a secondary indicator of popularity is the number of 'likes' given to that shot, but because not everybody who likes a shot will necessarily click on the button, once again it is just an indicator
- **Time**: to put the views and hearts in perspective, the analysis needs to take into account the recency of the figures, because time longer that a shot has been around, the more potential views and hearts it will accumulate and therefore more recent views or hearts needs to be weighed higher
- **Rate**: the complementary measure of time is the rate at which the views and hearts have accumulated, so that a shot that suddenly gains lots of views and likes could be said in one way to be more popular because it's popularity has increased more rapidly

Of course, there may be other factors that are not so obvious and require more understanding of the underlying dataset plus the way that the algorithm has been developed to produce the 'picks' that are going to reflect the taste of the users and the trending patterns in the designs being produced. But those four factors will form the basis of the equation.

Comment: Agree with @Michael Lai